# Java Logback: how do I rewrite log file for each log entry?

Tags: java, logback

I have logback in my Java project.
I configure it programmatically, it looks like

```
    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    ple.setPattern(DEFAULT_PATTERN);
    ple.setContext(lc);
    ple.start();
    FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    fileAppender.setFile("mylog.log");
    fileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
    fileAppender.setContext(lc);
    fileAppender.start();

    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(key+"");
    logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
```

How can I change this configuration to make it overwriting log file when next log entry comes? I.e. I dont need to append new lines to log, I need to have only last line there.